# How to run specific where claus in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I write a query. It is work but i need to add one more column.

So, my sql query like is :

`AND TESTTEST(coName, 3) IN ('1','2')`

I try

`->whereIn("coName",[1,2])`

but how to use select(coName,3) ?

```
    ->whereIn("coName",[1,2])
    ->get();
```

or Can I just directly run my query like is:
->whereRaw("TESTTEST(coName, 3) IN ('1','2')")

Is this a way?

Comment: What is 3 - is it the position of another column which you want to check the value against in `whereIn`?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly run raw query as

```
Model::whereRaw()->get();
```

or you can chain the where clause one after other. to get your desired result.
In Eloquent you do not have to specify the column number for your column.
you can write the query as

```
Model::where()->where()->get();
```

Comment: Is it run sql function?

Comment: you can run the sql as raw using whereRaw in laravel. you can take [this article](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-eloquent-whereraw-condition-exampleexample.html) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Also when you have multiple condition you can do this:

```
Model::whereIn('coName', [1,2])->where(['col1' => 'val1', 'col2' => 'val2'])->get();
```